# C# Exception Error Message Displayed Once

Tags: c#, .net, exception, try-catch

I'm trying to load a configuration to a device and when this device is disconnected it gives me an error which I handle with a try-catch block like this:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        LoadConfig();
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);//I want to display this more than once
    }
}
```

This works fine.

But sometimes I need to load the configuration a few times and I want to display the error message every time it fails, but it seems like this only works the first time and if another exception occurs after that then the message on that exception is not displayed.

Is there anything I could do? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you mean that you're clicking on your button and you want an error message each time you click, but you're only getting an error message the first time? That sound as if something is occurring within `LoadConfig()` that prevents an exception being thrown on subsequent attempts, not an issue with the try/catch.

Comment: Or you want to retry 5 times on a single click and show the exception message for each?

Comment: Ex**c**eption?)

Comment: @GlorinOakenfoot you were right, my problem it's not the try-catch, apparently the class provided to control my device is preventing that an exception occurs multiple times, thanks for the quick response